# How to install header files (for C) into my main directory?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, directory, mingw, header-files

Basically, I want to install certain header files into my main directory so that I only have to write `#include<headerfile.h>`, so that I don't have to always include it in my main working directory with `#include"headerfile.h"`.

I tried it with copy and pasting that header file into the location VSCode gives me when I look for the location of the header files (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt`) and I tried to use the location of Mingw (`C:\MinGW\include`). In both cases with no avail.

How exactly can I properly install non-standard header files?

Comment: In general, it's better not to try that, tempting though it is.  The files can get lost during upgrades rather easily.  On Unix-like systems, the default location for users to install such headers is `/usr/local/include` and the compilers often look there for headers by default.  I'm not sure whether there's an equivalent on Windows.

Comment: There is no way to avoid having the `#include` statements in your program.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the compiler doesn't know about directories other than the ones it uses to search for include files.  The `-I <dir>` allows you to specify extra directories to allow you to have this kind of material, but the problem is that you have to specify that on the build script.

For example, create a `${HOME}/include` directory, and put your headers in it.  You can then build your sources by using:

```
cc -I"${HOME}/include" -c your_file.c -o your_file.o
```

and this allows you to reference the include files you have in your `include` directory.

Of course, copying the include files to the standard location `/usr/include`  should work, but as I see you are using *Windows* environment, the exact location of the includes the compiler is reading is unknown to me.  You'll have to dig a little yourself to get the exact place to put them in.